# How to hide/show certain values inside Drop-down for Superuser in Django admin

Tags: django

I have a model with the the below field:

```
Choice_options=(
    ('Open',Open'),
    ('Pending','Pending'),
    ('Re-verify','Re-verify'),
    ('Approved',Approved'),
    ('Cancelled',Cancelled'),
)

class Sample(models,model):
    Choice=models.Charfield(Max_length=50,default='Open',choices=Choice_options)
```

When the superuser log in to this admin page, he should see only the following options in the choice field:
("Approved","Cancelled", Re-verify")

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `ModelForm` to specify how to edit the record:

```
# app/forms.py

from django import forms
from app.models import Sample

admin_choice_choices=(
    ('Pending', 'Pending'),
    ('Re-verify', 'Re-verify'),
    ('Approved', 'Approved'),
    ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled'),
)

class AdminSampleForm(forms.ModelForm):
    Choices = forms.ChoiceField(<b>choices=admin_choice_choices</b>)
    
    class Meta:
        model = Sample
        fields = '__all__'
```

In your `admin.py` you can then specify the form:

```
# app/admin.py

from django.contrib import admin
from app.forms import AdminSampleForm
from app.models import Sample

@admin.register(Sample)
class SampleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AdminSampleForm
```

---

> **Note**: normally the name of the fields in a Django model are written in *snake_case*, not *PerlCase*, so it should be: `choice` instead of <s>`Choice`</s>.